# Application Insight Config file is not adding to my windows 10 Universal app

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I fallowed the rules under this [url](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/08/12/adding-application-insights-to-a-windows-10-universal-app/), But Application Insight Config file is not showing to add Instrumentation Key, please help me to how to add application insights to my windows project.

Comment: Hai Devi, Could you please add more explanation for `"Insight Config file is not adding"` are you getting any error? or what is happening while adding ?

Comment: @un-lucky i fallowed http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/08/12/adding-application-insights-to-a-windows-10-universal-app/ url to add app insights to my app, after adding appinsights config file is not showing to add  Instrumentation Key..

Comment: Microsoft provides two solutions for device devOps: [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) for client side analytics; and Application Insights for the server side. For UWP app, it's better to use HockeyApp. For more info, see [Analytics for Windows Phone and Store apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started) and [Transitioning Mobile Apps from Application Insights to HockeyApp](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/transitioning-mobile-apps-from-application-insights-to-hockeyapp).

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT is there no way to add applicationinsights.config file..?

Comment: As you can see, it will stop accepting new apps for iOS, Android, Windows Store and Windows Phone in Application Insights from April 15, 2016 and On June 15, 2016, it will stop showing data in Application Insights for iOS, Android, Windows Store, and Windows Phone apps. So I'd suggest you use HockeyApp now in case of transition to HockeyApp later.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT HockeyApp is for sending crash reports and feeback, but i want to send pageview and duration is it possible...?please suggest me..

Comment: I'm not familiar with HockeyApp, but according to [HockeyApp Preseason](http://hockeyapp.net/preseason/), it supports User Metrics, you may hava a try.